# Migrating com.vividsolutions.jts to org.locationtech.jts still complaining about lack of com.vividsolutions package

Tags: java, dependencies, migrate, classnotfound, jts

I'm trying to upgrade dependencies for a java application that uses `com.vividsolutions.jts`. I have removed all the references to this library from pom.xml and replaced them by the ones from `org.locationtech.jts`.

I have updated all the imports to use `org.locationtech` version. However, in my function I'm still getting an error related to `com.vividsolutions` object not being imported.

```
import org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContext;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LinearRing;

import org.locationtech.spatial4j.shape.jts.JtsGeometry;


// ... other stuff

public static myFunc() {
    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    LinearRing linear = gf.createLinearRing(coordinates);
    JtsGeometry poly = new JtsGeometry(fact.createPolygon(linear), JtsSpatialContext.GEO, true, true);
}
```

Here's the error that I get for the last line of the above code: `[ERROR] cannot access com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry [ERROR]   class file for com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry not found`

I'm clearly importing `JtsGeometry` from the new library at `org.locationtech`, however, it's still thinking the old library should be used.

The old library isn't in the dependency tree or the code anymore, as the followings don't return anything:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep vivid
rg vivid
```

Any idea what I'm missing here or how I should troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what was wrong with the vividsolutions library inclusion. However, I was able to resolve my issue by including both of these in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
        <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.locationtech.spatial4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>spatial4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Initially I didn't have the second dependency in the `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Well presumably they have put >some< of the `org.locationtech.jts.geom.*` classes into the `spatial4j` dependency.  You should be able to figure it out by looking at what is inside the JAR files.